# LED color changing according to battery charge status?

Tags: diodes

I would like to set up the circuit to charge the 3.7V Li-ion battery using diodes, capacitors,leds,resistors and a zener diode.I have a few questions.
1)The color of the led while the battery is charging:
-Charging: red
-When the charging is complete: green
How do I do that?
2)To charge 3.7V battery, how much DC voltage should I apply to the battery?
Thank you all!
[image]

Comment: You can't safely (and practically) charge a Li-ion battery with just those components. Its charging profile is basically constant current, then constant voltage after a threshold.

Comment: I am at the beginning level for electronics.Please chech my circuit: https://ibb.co/cipHmx

Comment: @bopele: Put the image into your post so that we don't have to follow links. Turn off the grid to improve legibility before taking a screen grab.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Li-ION battery charging IC. It is designed to be safe.

Comment: While this may be good advice is does not answer the question which is about charge status indication.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I adjust the LED color according to the charge status?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a LED that changes color.
You only get one fixed color from one LED.

But you can get multi-color LEDs which are actually multiple LEDs combined together in one package, where the light mixes together from the adjacent LED dies.

For example, you could turn on either the red die or the green die, or both, and when they're both turned on you get orange-yellow light from the red and green mixed together.

Such LEDs are typically commoned together (either on the anode or the cathode), so you have three pins - one for each LED, plus one common. (You can also get anti-parallel bicolor LEDs with two wires, and reversing the polarity changes the color. These can't be put into a "both on" orange state.)

So, if you imagine designing a circuit that has two separate "charging in progress" and "charging complete" LEDs, then you can merge those together into a single "color changing" LED package. But you need to remember that these LEDs must be common on one side.

PS: Don't try charging a Li cell from a transformerless AC line power supply like that! It's really not safe and not going to work. And trying to draw any significant current from a transformerless capacitor-dropper AC line supply just won't work, it will fall over except at small loads. Not to mention the risk of the battery exploding, and electric shock risk from the non-isolated power supply.

Comment: Thank you but I can only use diodes, resistors, capacitors, zeners, transistors and opamps to set up a battery charger circuit. I can not use Transformer because my Professor does not allow it.Can not the 3-pin LED be used with the above circuit?

Comment: I hope this is only a thought experiment, and your teachers don't require you to do any lab work that will start lithium fires.

What are your assumptions about the voltage source?
This looks like a classic "transformerless power supply" connected to the AC line, with a capacitive reactance that drops the voltage, across a capacitor.

Does your system really need to have 115 (or 230) VAC supplied to its input port? Could the assumption of the input voltage of this hypothetical system be changed to, say, 5VDC?

Comment: I can use the signal generator in the lab, so I can get a value between 0-100 Vac.On the output, I have to get 5VDC. I should design the led circuit with Opamp, but i have no idea about decision circuits..

Comment: Sounds like you want a comparator.
Any opamp can act as a relatively low-performance comparator, and will do the job for your basic purposes. When the non-inverting input exceeds the inverting input, with the opamp open loop, the output will go high right up (close) to Vcc.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator